# How to stop a onclick event when other button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

When the `#terminateButton` is clicked, I want `#myButton` to not show the alert when clicked and remove the `onclick` event. I tried to add `removeEventListener` but it did not work.

```js
let element = document.getElementById("myButton");

element.onclick = a
document.getElementById("terminateButton").onclick = function () {
  element.innerHTML = "Does Nothing";
  element.removeEventListener('click',a)
};

function a(){
    alert('You clicked the button');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id='myButton'>Shows alert</button>
    <button id='terminateButton'>Dont show alert when other button clicked</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi iMightjustGiveYouaBite, did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your event listener with `addEventListener` function to be able to remove it with `removeEventListener`, like below. Here what [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) says:

> The `removeEventListener()` method of the `EventTarget` interface removes an event listener previously registered with `EventTarget.addEventListener()` from the target.

```js
let element = document.getElementById("myButton");

element.addEventListener("click", a)

document.getElementById("terminateButton").onclick = function () {
  element.innerHTML = "Does Nothing";
  element.removeEventListener('click', a)
};

function a(){
    alert('You clicked the button');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id='myButton'>Shows alert</button>
    <button id='terminateButton'>Dont show alert when other button clicked</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```